# CSS3 :nth-child() Selector is not working

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS from codecademy. there on a exercise I coded :

```
<body>
    <h3 class="fancy">heading</h3>
    <p class="fancy">yuvt q</p>
    <p id="serious">hdtrgggfdrr</p>
    <p id="one">jwiox</p>
</body>
```

and as css I typed :

```
.fancy{
font-family:Cursive;
color: violet
};
#serious{
font-family:Courier;
color:#8c8c8c
};
body :nth-child(4) {
font-size: 26px;
}
```

here I wanna make third paragraph of size 26px, which is 4th child. but the code is not working. I haved discussed a lot in codecademy forum but still it is not working any suggestions.

Comment: It's not working because you have a syntax error, that strange misplaced `;` between the `#serious` and `body :nth-child(4)` selectors. Without the semi-colon your CSS [seems to work perfectly well](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1updmth3/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is incorrect formatting on the css. Each statment must end in a semicolon, but there should be no semicolons after the brackets. Like this:

```
.fancy{
    font-family:Cursive;
    color: violet;
}
#serious{
    font-family:Courier;
    color:#8c8c8c;
}
body :nth-child(4) {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
body :nth-child(4) {
font-size: 26px;
}
```

To:

```
p:nth-child(4) {
font-size: 26px;
}
```

More info here:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: And, other than specifying that the element to style is a `<p>` - making it less generic - how does this resolve the problem reported by the OP?

Comment: @DavidThomas This is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: No, it's not; the OP asked for suggestions as to why his/her original code wasn't working. Which is because of the typo, which is entirely independent of the use of `body p:nth-child(4)`, `p:nth-child(4)` or the original `body :nth-child(4)`.

Comment: The syntax for :nth-child is `element:nth-child(an + b) { style properties }`. You cannot omit `element`in this.

Comment: [I beg to differ](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1updmth3/2/); refer to the specs: "[`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)."

Comment: Actually, you are completely right. nth-of-type requires you state an element, :nth-child also works without an element. Thanks for making me look it up! Couldn't find it here before: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo I really wish the specs would be more explicit sometimes!

Comment: @DavidThomas I believe the OP intended to use "body:nth-child".  The point I was making is that the element should be the element which is the child, not the parent.  Therefore, I recommended changing the "body" to a "p", since the element he wanted affected was a <p>.  "body" represents the parent, which should not be the element used in this syntax.   It's obvious that the OP isn't trying to make a production-ready site, but is trying to learn the syntax.   The solution provided should help him understand.

Comment: In which case the explanation should have been in the answer itself, surely; then it would have been somewhat more useful. However, since you seem to have corrected a working, valid selector with an alternative (though equally valid, and more restrictive) selector I'm not seeing the advantage of the change. Also, you silently fixed the actual problems of the trailing `;` characters separating the CSS style-definitions from the subsequent selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

HTML

```
<body>
    <h3 class="fancy">heading</h3>
    <p class="fancy">yuvt q</p>
    <p id="serious">hdtrgggfdrr</p>
    <p id="one">jwiox</p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.fancy{
    font-family:Cursive;
    color: violet;
}
#serious{
    font-family:Courier;
    color:#8c8c8c;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

OK so the p:nth-child(4) will select the 4th paragraph in your code and you also had semicolons in the wrong place. .test{background: #000;} <-- always end with a semicolon before moving onto the next line.

Comment: "*Here you go*" - please take the time to explain how your posted code solves the questions that are being asked, just posting working code is of limited use if the OP - and others, in future - have to spend time dissecting the code to find the changes before then having to research *why* those changes were made.

Comment: So I saw, welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for joining us! Incidentally, if you have any problems with the site, this is purely for reference and *not* indicative of any problem I might have with your answer, take a look at [meta] and the problem/question you have may have been answered there or feel free to ask a new question if not. :)

Comment: Okay, so your worsened your answer. Doublecheck your statement as of where to put semicolons, man...

Comment: Fixed, Thanks for pointing that out. Time for a coffee